# Deshabiltar boton desde metodo Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

necesito deshabilitar un botón desde el siguiente metodo:

```java
public void test(String firma){        
        try{
            //botonFirma.setEnabled(false);
            botonFirma.setClickable(false);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

He "inicializado" los botones en el onCreate de esta forma:

```java
public class IndexActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    Button botonCamara, botonFirma;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //btnCamara = findViewById(R.id.btnCamara);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);         
         botonFirma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFirma);
    }
}
```

Pero cuando ejecuto el metodo, me arroja el error

`java.lang.nullpointerexception: attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.button.setclickable(boolean)' on a null object reference`

Alguna solución, es posible hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Si defines la variable `botonFirma` a nivel de clase y obtienes la referencia del botòn mediante `findViewById()`, pero al llamar el metodo `setClickable()` del boton marca

> java.lang.nullpointerexception: attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.button.setclickable(boolean)' on a null object
>   reference

**Esto indica que el boton con id `btnFirma` no existe dentro del layout `activity_index.xml`**

---

Por cierto para deshabilitar un botòn, se realiza mediante el mètodo `setEnabled()` , ejemplo:

```
myButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, si entiendo el porque de el error, pero no he podido solucionarlo, si fueras tan amable de decirme como podria solucionarlo